# Why and how exactly do spinning electrons create a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, spin-models

I have just been told that if you had a spinning electron completely isolated, even that one electron would have a magnetic north and south pole. I have also been told that all metals have spinning electrons in, and in some metals, the electrons are all spinning randomly, so the mini north and south poles around each one cancel out, meaning that lump of metal has no overall magnetic field. In other metals, the spinning electrons all spin together in such a way that there is an overall north and south pole.

I tried to visualize this by imagining a rectangular magnet with the south pole on the left side and the north pole on the right side, where rows of electrons run parallel to these sides all the way along the magnet. Each electron is spinning, and has its personal magnetic north on the right, and its personal magnetic south on the left. This lead me to wonder whether the reason the overall magnet would have a magnetic north and south would be because at the right hand, north end of the magnet, all of the magnetic norths of the electrons are lined up along it (with all of the magnetic souths further back) but at the left hand, south end of the magnet, all of the magnetic souths of the electrons would be lined up against that end. I have no idea whether this is what is really happening in a magnet, and whether the electrons would be lined up in rows at all, but does my idea happen to be the correct one (unlikely, I know!) and if not, what is the microscopic explanation? There seems to be surprisingly little information on the internet explaining magnetism in terms of spinning electrons rather than just in terms of vague terms like "domain", so I would really appreciate a clear explanation (if there is one).

Also, why even would a spinning negative charge create a magnetic dipole? What would happen if you spun a positive charge (such as a proton)? And I know that you can create the disturbances in electric and magnetic fields called electromagnetic waves by vibrating a charged particle (which is intuitive in that obviously moving an electrically charged particle around would make its electric field wobble and vibrate around) but why would vibrating that charged particle create disturbances in magnetic field when I thought that only spinning electrons had a magnetic field, not simply any charged particle vibrating from side to side?

Comment: Any moving charged particle produces a magnetic field

Comment: What are your sources? Magnetism is not the easiest subject. Choose your sources with care, for example the Feynman Lectures should give a good introduction.

Comment: @DKNguyen, so does that mean that even a moving proton would produce a magnetic field? Also, does that mean that it doesn't matter in what way the particle is moving, so even a side to side vibration would produce a magnetic field?

Comment: @my2cts, I'm doing IGCSE physics, and am using Khan Academy as my main resource, with textbooks as a supplement. Thanks so much for the Feynman recommendation! Does it matter what order I watch his lectures in?

Comment: @Willow Yes...I imagine a side to side motion would produce an oscillating magnetic field

Comment: To add to the discussion without committing to a full answer: side-to-side motion is indeed well studied and called "radiation". The reasoning you're looking for is likely "Electromagnetic induction", and the true microscopic phenomenon is indeed "spin" but more than likely is not equivalent to your intuition. "Spin" of an electron is *not* related to a rotational motion of the electron, and there are many detailed descriptions of this quantum mechanical effect.